# Get MainWindowTitle equivalent in java

Tags: java

i have this code about how to get the current running process using c#.net, it uses System.Diagnostics and Process i wonder how can i get this equivalent to java. i found many research but it does not give me the right answer.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process[] process = new System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcess();

foreach(Process p in process)
{
    if(p.MainWindowTitle > 0)
    {
      console.writeline(p.MainwindowTitle);
    }
}
```

something like that!

Comment: You would need JNI or JNA for this, and my preference would be the latter, JNA.

Comment: Unless you're talking about simply getting the main title of a Swing JFrame, and then it's trivial -- `myJFrame.getTitle()`. But if you're trying to get the window title of your non-GUI window, then you'll need to delve into the OS's internals, and you can't do that with just core Java.

Comment: Get all the  current running process not the one of jframe itself

Comment: Then yeah, JNA is what you want to use. The reason it's more difficult in Java is that Java was built to be OS agnostic, and whenever you try to do something that gets too close to the inner workings of the OS, you have to leave core Java and use a platform-dependent solution of one type or another.

Answer (score 0):

JNA is what you want to use. The reason it's more difficult in Java is that Java was built to be OS agnostic, and whenever you try to do something that gets too close to the inner workings of the OS, you have to leave core Java and use a platform-dependent solution of one type or another.

For instance, this is one way of getting the names of the windows currently running using JNA, but I haven't yet figured out how to limit it to just the top level windows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public class EnumAllWindowNames {
   static interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
      User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

      interface WNDENUMPROC extends StdCallCallback {
         boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer arg);
      }

      boolean EnumWindows(WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer userData);

      int GetWindowTextA(Pointer hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);

      Pointer GetWindow(Pointer hWnd, int uCmd);

      Pointer GetParent(Pointer hWnd);

      Pointer GetAncestor(Pointer hWnd, int gaFlags);
   }

   public static String[] ignoreArray = { "Default", "MSCTFIME", "???????", "Msg",
         "SysFader" };

   public static boolean ignore(String text) {
      for (String ignoreText : ignoreArray) {
         if (ignoreText.contains(text)) {
            return true;
         }
      }
      return false;
   }

   public static List<String> getAllWindowNames() {
      final List<String> windowNames = new ArrayList<String>();
      final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
      user32.EnumWindows(new User32.WNDENUMPROC() {

         @Override
         public boolean callback(Pointer hWnd, Pointer arg) {
            byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
            user32.GetWindowTextA(hWnd, windowText, 512);
            String wText = Native.toString(windowText).trim();
            if (!ignore(wText)) {
               if (user32.GetParent(hWnd) == null) {
                  windowNames.add(wText);
               }
            }
            return true;
         }
      }, null);

      return windowNames;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<String> winNameList = getAllWindowNames();
      for (String winName : winNameList) {
         System.out.println(winName);
      }
   }

}
```

This requires the use of two jna jar files: platform.jar and jna.jar.